# Add two pandas dataframes with different indices

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have two dataframes, each one having a lot of columns and rows. The elements in each row are the same, but their indexing is different. I want to add the elements of one of the columns of the two dataframes.

As a basic example consider the following two Series:

```
Sr1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index = [0, 1, 2, 3])
Sr2 = pd.Series([3,4,-3,6], index = [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Say that each row contains the same element, only in different indexing. I want to add the two columns and get in the end a new column that contains `[4,6,0,10]`. Instead, due to the indices, I get `[nan, 5, 7, 1]`.

Is there an easy way to solve this without changing the indices?

I want output as a series.

Comment: What is the format of the expected output? A list or a series?

Comment: If you don't want to worry about index align, I suggest you use numpy arrays.

Comment: Hi, it should be a Series.

Comment: What indices should the output series have then? This info should be added to the question too

Comment: Right, sorry about that. It doesn't really matter, but say the Sr1 ones. The resulting series will be summed over all rows to produce a single number.

Comment: Can I ask why do you want a series instead of a numpy array for example if indices do not matter?

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `reset_index(drop=True)`:

```
Sr1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index = [0, 1, 2, 3])
Sr2 = pd.Series([3,4,-3,6], index = [1, 2, 3, 4])

Sr1 + Sr2.reset_index(drop=True)

0     4
1     6
2     0
3    10
dtype: int64
```

Also,

```
pd.Series(Sr1.values + Sr2.values, index=Sr1.index)
```

Comment: RIght, this `reset_index` won't mess with the index of the original Series, but only be used temporarily. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `reset_index` on one or more series:

```
Sr1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index = [0, 1, 2, 3])
Sr2 = pd.Series([3,4,-3,6], index = [1, 2, 3, 4])

res = Sr1 + Sr2.reset_index(drop=True)

0     4
1     6
2     0
3    10
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

Sr1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index = [0, 1, 2, 3])
Sr2 = pd.Series([3,4,-3,6], index = [1, 2, 3, 4])

sr3 = [sum(i) for i in zip(Sr1, Sr2)]
print(sr3)
```

**Output:**

```
[4, 6, 0, 10]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Zip is neat. Didn't know about it. I was hoping the result would be a Series, as i said above.

Comment: iteration, when pandas and numpy are involved, is unnecessary and doesn't scale well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html), which gives you a numpy representation, and then you can add them like this:

```
Sr1.values + Sr2.values
```